# Searching the nearest node from the dead-end node on osmnx?

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

I'm learning how to show the map and show the data from the open street map as osmnx.
I wannt to show shortest pass from dead end node to reach the nearest node.
I want to this nearest node on the highway.
I understand how to show dead end point and the node points on the highway, and make shortest pass between two nodes I select.
But I dont know how to search and select the nearest nodes on the highway from the dead end nodes.
Could you tell me how to search for the nearest node from the dead end point which I select?
Thanks!
*I reposted

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from colorspacious import cspace_converter

G = ox.graph_from_point(center_point=(35.6522, 139.7296), dist=1000, simplify=True, retain_all=False, network_type="drive")
ox.plot_graph(G)

gdf_edges1 = gdf_edges[gdf_edges['highway'] == 'secondary']
gdf_edges1

**# dead_end nodes**
dead_end = gdf_nodes[gdf_nodes["street_count"] == 1]
dead_end

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(100, 100))
gdf_edges.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=1, edgecolor="blue")

dead_end.plot(ax=ax, color="green", markersize=1000)

# Tokyo_town.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="none", edgecolor="black")

ax.set_axis_off()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

**# nodes on highway=primary or secoundary**

selected_edges = []
for u, v, key, data in G.edges(keys=True, data=True):
    if data['highway'] == 'secondary':
        selected_edges.append((u, v))

selected_nodes = set()
for u, v in selected_edges:
    selected_nodes.add(u)
    selected_nodes.add(v)

node_data = []
for node in selected_nodes:
    node_data.append(G.nodes[node])

higway_nodes_df = pd.DataFrame(node_data)
higway_nodes_df

fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, show=False, close=False, edge_color='gray', edge_alpha=0.6, node_size=0)

higway_nodes_df.plot(x='x', y='y', kind='scatter', ax=ax, color='red', alpha=0.6, s=10)

# each point
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    ax.text(row['x'], row['y'], f"({row['x']:.10f}, {row['y']:.5f})", fontsize=20, ha='left', va='bottom', color='red')

plt.show()

**#I don't know how to find the nearest nodes from the dead end node.**

**#this is example, making shortest pass**
# start and end
starting_point = (35.6573758, 139.7287814 )
ending_point = (35.6584, 139.72393390000)

nearest_origin_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, starting_point[1], starting_point[0])
nearest_destination_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, ending_point[1], ending_point[0])

# shortest
shortest_path = nx.shortest_path(G, nearest_origin_node, nearest_destination_node, weight="length")

# plot output
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph_route(G, shortest_path, route_linewidth=6, node_size=0, bgcolor="w", show=False, close=False, figsize=(10, 10))

# start and end 
ax.scatter(starting_point[1], starting_point[0], c="red", edgecolor="black", s=100, label="Starting Point")
ax.scatter(ending_point[1], ending_point[0], c="green", edgecolor="black", s=100, label="Ending Point")

# legend
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```